# Why does $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) = 0$ imply that $\beta f=0$ on $\beta \mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, compactification

This is a question about $\beta \mathbb{N}$, the Čech-Stone compactification of the natural numbers.

I'm reading a proof of the fact that every zeroset in $\beta X \setminus X$ contains a copy of $\beta \mathbb{N}$ (Where $X$ is an arbitrary Tychonov space). The author implicitly uses the fact that if
$$f:\mathbb{N}\to [0,1]$$
goes to zero for $n\to \infty$, then it's unique extension $\beta f$ is zero on the remainder $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$. Intuitively this makes a lot of sense but I can't translate that intuition into a solid argument. How can one prove this?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0$ means $\lim f(\mathscr{F}) =  0$, where $\mathscr{F}$ is the Fréchet filter on $\mathbb{N}$. Since every free filter - in particular every free ultrafilter - on $\mathbb{N}$ is finer than $\mathscr{F}$, it follows that $\lim f(\mathscr{U}) = 0$ for every free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$. But $\beta \mathbb{N}$ can be canonically identified with the ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$, and $\beta f(\mathscr{U}) = \lim f(\mathscr{U})$ with that identification.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer. I love that there is a net answer and a filter answer and I whish I could accept them both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{N}$ is dense in $\beta\mathbb{N}$. Thus for any $x\in\beta\mathbb{N}$ there is a net $(x_\alpha)\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ convergent to $x$.

By the continuity of the extension $F:\beta\mathbb{N}\to[0,1]$ we have

$$F(x)=\lim_\alpha f(x_\alpha)$$

Now if $x\not\in\mathbb{N}$ then $f(x_\alpha)\to 0$ by the assumption because in that case $(x_\alpha)$ cannot be bounded.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't tried nets yet as I usually work with filters, but this is a really simple argument. Nice answer!